# How do I compare multiple arrays in azure policy?

Tags: azure-policy

I'm trying to create a policy for **Application Gateway**. The policy is described as below

> Http listener should not be attached to a public IP frontend configuration

So in my understanding, I've to check if the *frontendConfiguration* does have public IP and then check if the name of the public IP is being referenced in any of the *httpListeners*

Since both frontendIPConfigurations and httpListeners are arrays, I thought of using a count for this complex query and tried the following

```
"if": {
                "count": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations[*]",
                    "where": {
                        "allOf": [
                            {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations[*].publicIPAddress.id",
                                "exists": true
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/httpListeners[*].frontendIPConfiguration.id",
                                "like": "[concat('*', field('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations[*].publicIPAddress.name'))]"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "greaterOrEquals": 1
            },
```

But I get the following error

> The alias: 'Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/httpListeners[*].frontendIPConfiguration.id' used inside the 'count.where' expression is targeting an array outside of the count scope: 'Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations[*]'

Can you please let me know if there's a way around this?

Here's a sample ARM template for reference:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "applicationGatewayName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "tier": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "skuSize": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "capacity": {
            "type": "int",
            "defaultValue": 2
        },
        "subnetName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "zones": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "virtualNetworkName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "virtualNetworkPrefix": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "publicIpAddressName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "sku": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "allocationMethod": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "publicIpZones": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "privateIpAddress": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "autoScaleMaxCapacity": {
            "type": "int"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "vnetId": "[resourceId('policy-tester','Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
        "publicIPRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]",
        "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]",
        "applicationGatewayId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('applicationGatewayName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('applicationGatewayName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
            "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "zones": "[parameters('zones')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {
                "sku": {
                    "name": "[parameters('skuSize')]",
                    "tier": "[parameters('tier')]"
                },
                "gatewayIPConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "appGatewayIpConfig",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "frontendIPConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "appGwPrivateFrontendIp",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                            },
                            "privateIPAddress": "[parameters('privateIpAddress')]",
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "appGwPublicFrontendIp",
                        "properties": {
                            "PublicIPAddress": {
                                "id": "[variables('publicIPRef')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "frontendPorts": [
                    {
                        "name": "port_80",
                        "properties": {
                            "Port": 80
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "port_8080",
                        "properties": {
                            "Port": 8080
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "backendAddressPools": [
                    {
                        "name": "samplebend",
                        "properties": {
                            "backendAddresses": []
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "backendHttpSettingsCollection": [
                    {
                        "name": "sample-http",
                        "properties": {
                            "Port": 80,
                            "Protocol": "Http",
                            "cookieBasedAffinity": "Disabled",
                            "requestTimeout": 20
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "httpListeners": [
                    {
                        "name": "sample-list",
                        "properties": {
                            "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                                "id": "[concat(variables('applicationGatewayId'), '/frontendIPConfigurations/appGwPublicFrontendIp')]"
                            },
                            "frontendPort": {
                                "id": "[concat(variables('applicationGatewayId'), '/frontendPorts/port_80')]"
                            },
                            "protocol": "Http",
                            "sslCertificate": null
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "sample-priv-http",
                        "properties": {
                            "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                                "id": "[concat(variables('applicationGatewayId'), '/frontendIPConfigurations/appGwPrivateFrontendIp')]"
                            },
                            "frontendPort": {
                                "id": "[concat(variables('applicationGatewayId'), '/frontendPorts/port_8080')]"
                            },
                            "protocol": "Http",
                            "sslCertificate": null
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "requestRoutingRules": [
                    {
                        "Name": "sample-rule",
                        "properties": {
                            "RuleType": "Basic",
                            "httpListener": {
                                "id": "[concat(variables('applicationGatewayId'), '/httpListeners/sample-list')]"
                            },
                            "backendAddressPool": {
                                "id": "[concat(variables('applicationGatewayId'), '/backendAddressPools/samplebend')]"
                            },
                            "backendHttpSettings": {
                                "id": "[concat(variables('applicationGatewayId'), '/backendHttpSettingsCollection/sample-http')]"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "sample-priv-http-rule",
                        "properties": {
                            "RuleType": "Basic",
                            "httpListener": {
                                "id": "[concat(variables('applicationGatewayId'), '/httpListeners/sample-priv-http')]"
                            },
                            "backendAddressPool": {
                                "id": "[concat(variables('applicationGatewayId'), '/backendAddressPools/samplebend')]"
                            },
                            "backendHttpSettings": {
                                "id": "[concat(variables('applicationGatewayId'), '/backendHttpSettingsCollection/sample-http')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "enableHttp2": false,
                "sslCertificates": [],
                "probes": [],
                "autoscaleConfiguration": {
                    "minCapacity": "[parameters('capacity')]",
                    "maxCapacity": "[parameters('autoScaleMaxCapacity')]"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": "[parameters('virtualNetworkPrefix')]"
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "default",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
            "name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
            },
            "zones": "[parameters('publicIpZones')]",
            "properties": {
                "publicIPAllocationMethod": "[parameters('allocationMethod')]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Naveen, I'm trying to create this policy too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: My colleague asked Azure Support regarding this and it seems, unfortunately, Its not supported in Azure.

Comment: I created the following issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/issues/652 asking for an alias that may help us create the policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft, but this is not an official answer*

The following policy should do the trick:

```json
{
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways"
      },
      {
        "count": {
          "field": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations[*]",
          "where": {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations[*].publicIPAddress.id",
                "exists": true
              },
              {
                "value": "[format('{0}/frontendIPConfigurations/{1}', field('id'), current('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations[*].name'))]",
                "in": "[field('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/httpListeners[*].frontendIPConfiguration.id')]"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "greater": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}
```

**Details**

The condition:

```json
{
    "value": "[format('{0}/frontendIPConfigurations/{1}', field('id'), current('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations[*].name'))]",
    "in": "[field('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/httpListeners[*].frontendIPConfiguration.id')]"
}
```

Checks if the resource ID of the current frontendIPConfiguration (that has a public IP) is being referenced by any of the httpListeners.

The `value` expression builds the resource ID of the frontendIPConfiguration that is currently being evaluated by combining the resource ID for the app GW resource + the name of the current frontendIPConfiguration resource. We have to build it from scratch because the `id` property of the frontendIPConfiguration is not present in the request content when creating new app gw resource.

Also note that when you want to access the value of the current array member that's being enumerated by the `count` expression, you [should use the `current()` function instead of `field()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#the-current-function).

Regarding the error message you encountered, this is because the expression:

```json
{
  "field": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/httpListeners[*].frontendIPConfiguration.id",
  "like": "[concat('*', field('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations[*].publicIPAddress.name'))]"
}
```

Implicitly checks whether **all** the values of `Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/httpListeners[*].frontendIPConfiguration.id` match the condition (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/author-policies-for-arrays#referencing-the-array-members-collection)). This is basically a different form of a count expression, and as the error message says, you can't enumerate one array from inside an expression that enumerates a different array.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an account explicitly to say thank you for the answer provided by Elad Perets, but don't have enough reputation to comment or upvote. I've made some slight adjustments to the policy definition which have helped me and allow it be copied in to the Portal without errors:

```json
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways"
        },
        {
          "count": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations[*]",
            "where": {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations[*].publicIPAddress.id",
                  "exists": true
                },
                {
                  "value": "[format('{0}/frontendIPConfigurations/{1}', field('id'), current('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations[*].name'))]",
                  "in": "[field('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/httpListeners[*].frontendIPConfiguration.id')]"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "greater": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "effect": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Effect",
        "description": "Deny, Audit or Disabled the execution of the Policy"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "Deny",
        "Audit",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Audit"
    }
  }
}
```